# Connect from MS-DOS to shared folder

Tags: networking, windows-xp, ms-dos

I have problem with connecting to shared folder from MS-DOS. I can easily connect to it from Windows 7. 
The system I am working on was migrated. Before both computers were in domain and communication was ok. Now I need to just connect MS-DOS to Win-XP shared folder.

with `net use x: \\computername\sharename` after loging with correct user and password I get: "Error 5 access has been denied"

Searching for problem solution I have already:
1. Checked LM & NTLM responses setting on WinXP
2. Ping computer I am trying to connect to

Comment: See section 3 of [Configuration for Windows 7 (not required for Windows XP & below)](https://sites.google.com/site/probehouse/networking-the-atari/mounting-a-windows-shared-folder---sharitylight)

Comment: which MS-DOS version? which networking software/package are you using on MS-DOS machine?

Comment: @gogoud MS-DOS version 6.22, MS-DOS LAN Manager v2.1 Netbind, Microsoft DOS TCP/IP 1.0a

Comment: Read this in case it's helpful for this issue: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Sharing_files_with_DOS

Comment: you need a double backslash before the computer name, also make sure the XP machine is in the same Workgroup as the MS-DOS machine.